# What is a good synonym for "prevention" that can be used as a prefix?

Tags: synonyms, prefixes

I am writing a technical research paper and presenting my study on a phenomenon called "aliasing." So, basically, in the literature, something called "de-aliasing" exists to remove "aliasing," and it is prevalent. So, something is already "aliased," and the researchers try to "de-aliase" to reverse the process. It is like damage control.

My paper is about how to prevent aliasing. So, I wanted to form a catchy name as "de-aliasing" for this, but nothing fits nicely. I tried something like "avert-aliasing". Does it sound good? I am eager to hear your opinion.

Comment: *Anti-aliasing*?

Comment: [Anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) is indeed the common term.

Comment: The prefix [anti-](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti) is used both for prevention and for combatting/curing something already occurring, so it does not purely mean prevention, but it has "serving to prevent, cure, or alleviate" as a meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I also checked anti-aliasing, but i think in technical context, anti-aliasing is usually a very obvious way of addressing aliasing. In short I feel it's more like having an expensive instrument that can solve all my issues, but not an innovative or novel solution. Or, it's used to prevent aliasing when you already have a very nice picture and want to compress it and for the compressed form you want to avoid aliasing. However, it also makes sense to use “anti-alisaing” for both cure and prevention. So, i may use this.

Comment: alias filtering, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ***counter-*** . . .

**counter-alias** *verb*
**counter-aliasing** *noun*

> **counter-** *prefix*
> **1.**
> **1.a.**
> *verbs*, as **counteract** *v.*, **counter-make** *v.*, **countersay** *v.*, **counterweigh** *v.*, **counterwork** *v.*, with their derivatives: which see in their alphabetic places. Also many
> nonce-words, either contextual, or framed as literal equivalents of
> French or Italian verbs in *contre-*, *contra-*, expressing the doing
> of a thing or performance of an action in the opposite direction or
> sense, with a contrary effect, or in opposition, retort, or response
> to the action expressed by the simple verb; sometimes with the notion
> of rivalling or outdoing, checking or frustrating that action;
> sometimes merely in reciprocation. Such verbs were formerly more
> frequently formed and used than now. (These are hyphenated, but were
> formerly often written entire. The main stress is on the verb.)
> **2.**
> **2.a.**
>  With sense ‘(actor or action) against or in opposition’. (Stress on the root-word.)
> **2.h.**
>  Having the contrary tendency, nature, action, or position; running counter (to something else); opposing, opposite,
> contrary. (The stress is usually equal, as in adjective + substantive,
> and the prefix tends to be written separately: see **counter**
> *adj.*)
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

(You could really nonce it up with ***contraliasing***.)

Comment: This is great! I think this is what I was looking for; dunno why I didn't think of it. I will pitch this to my supervisors and see what they think. With one word, it sounds even better! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing is a common phenomenon when you're dealing with ultrasound or graphic-design. If your equipment is incapable of developing aliasing, it can be called **anti-aliasing** enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will definitely consider this.